# How to create realistic ball drop from cliff using swift and UIkit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, physics, uikit-dynamics

I try to make the ball with realistic physics when it fall from cliff, as you can see in in image 2. that's what I what to achieve, for now I have what is drawn in image 1.[image: Image of ball phisics]

for image 1. I use this code:

```
ball.center.x += 5
ball.center.y -= 4
```

By the way, in game cliff is slowly going down and ball up, after ball drops from cliff, cliff stops and ball just drop to the floor.

**Question** how can I make something like what I draw in image 2. Is there a easy way to do this, because I am not yet a good friend with physics.

Comment: consider to accept an answer if it solves your problem by pressing tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a logarithm function to generate values for x and y 
You can check more here: [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)

After importing UIKIT or FOUNDATION it will be like this in Swift:

```
func log2(x: Double) -> Double

func log2f(x: Float) -> Float
```

Comment: excuse me, but can you give me an example how to pass ball.x values to log? do I need to crate new var in func? I understand how log works, but can't figure out how to imply in to my code

Comment: @artG in your question you are showing end point and swift calculates all points between start point and end point automatically. So you need to create a function with timer in your anyamtion method. E.g. for every 0.1 sec y is changing linearly and x is changing logarithmically